# Facing error with JMeter in Non-GUI mode. Error: "Malformed option -"

Tags: jmeter, load, performance-testing

I am using Jmeter(5.1.1) in Non-GUI mode and unable to execute it. It still runs fine in GUI mode but fails in Non-GUI with "Error: Malformed option -". I removed the listeners from the JMX file but it still has some HTTP Request which are disabled will that be the problem here.? 
I am currently using this command in my Windows 7 machine with Java 8.

Commands:

```
jmeter -n -t (location: C:\Users\File.jmx) -l (location: C:\Users\Results.csv)
```

Its not showing results neither updating the results.csv file, after each run its just showing "

> **Error: Malformed option -**

" in command window. Can someone tell me what i am missing or what should i follow.?

Comment: You are adding `(location: ` to execution?

Comment: yes, will that work or it will auto create the results.jtl file.?

Answer (score 0):

Please use it like the below:-

jmeter -n -t D:\TestScripts\script.jmx -l D:\TestScripts\scriptresults.jtl

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried but still facing the same.

C:\bin\jmeter -n -t C:\TestScripts\script.jmx -l C:\TestScripts\scriptresults.jtl

My question is will "scriptresults.jtl" will create this as output file or i need to create this output file manually and add the location in Command window.?

Comment: It will automatically create the output file.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to go to Jmeter/bin path where your Jmeter jar is located.

(For Example, C:\apache-jmeter-5.0\bin)

Now after going to that path using cmd, use below command given that your abc.jmx file is at the above mentioned location only and once execution starts it will automatically create def.jtl at that location, hope this have given you clarity:

jmeter -n -t abc.jmx -l def.jtl

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so here what i was doing wrong. Dont know if this is stupid but might help others.

Since we use JMeter at work locations, my drive was linked with the cloud folder where none of the commands get execute i believe, so when i copy the installed JMeter folder and my JMX file to a Local location, say

before:

```
> C:\UsersABC\OneDrive-UserABC\JMETER\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin
```

Now:

```
> C:\JMET\apache-jmeter-5.1.1\bin
```

That OneDrive causing all the trouble. But thanks to all of you guys, you helped me figured this out. Thanks alot again :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while trying with "jmeter -n -t D:\load test 01\test.jmx -l D:\TestScripts\scriptresults.jtl" command.

Then I changed it to "jmeter -n -t D:\load_test_01\test.jmx -l D:\TestScripts\scriptresults.jtl" and it worked fine, in my case the issue was whitespaces in the folder name.

Comment: This does not seem to be the OP's issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps you can refer :-

1. Check JMETER file where you placed (Its is in backup folder / online )
2. Make sure JMX path has no space in between

   ref: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html
3. In task manager check same JMETER PROCESS ID running or not if yes close the PID
4. hpprof folder delete in bin folder